# Двоеточие, тире, запятая перед приложением?

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

Он сказал: духовенство должно выступить носителем нового послания к миру(:) послания открытости, терпимости, гуманизма, ...
Правильно ли стоит двоеточие в скобках, может быть надо поставить тире (или запятую)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он сказал: духовенство должно выступить носителем нового послания к миру —  послания открытости, терпимости, гуманизма, ..

**В конце предложения приложение** обычно обособляется тире, в данном предложении обособленное приложение носит пояснительный характер.

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

**Если предложение не заканчивается,** то также ставится одно (а не два) тире в том случае, если после обособленного приложения следует **запятая**.

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

§ 65. Приложения отделяются одиночным тире (второе тире поглощается другим знаком или опускается): 4) если по условиям контекста после приложения стоит запятая: **Проходя вдоль своего вагона — нашего временного жилища, увидели мы в окне знакомую физиономию** (тире поглощается запятой, отделяющей деепричастный оборот);